# When closing Kivy app settings, UI text changes don't work

Tags: python, kivy

When I start the following app and click btn2 I observe the text of the button change as I would expect. When I open settings using btn1, then close settings and then click btn2 the text does not change again, yet the button is pressed (message is printed). I have noticed this happening with other labels as well and I don't understand why. It should be noted that the callback is called as expected and the message printed with the same button instance.

While debugging this I also found that the counter keeps incrementing as expected but the text becomes an empty string after the settings are closed and updating it does not reflect onto the app UI.

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        btn1 = Button(text="Settings", size_hint=(.5, 1), on_press=self.btn1_on_press)
        btn2 = Button(text="0", size_hint=(.5, 1), on_press=self.btn2_on_press)
        self.add_widget(btn1)
        self.add_widget(btn2)
        self.counter = 0

    def btn1_on_press(self, btn):
        app.open_settings()

    def btn2_on_press(self, btn):
        print("btn pressed: ", btn)
        self.counter += 1
        btn.text = str(self.counter)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        return MainLayout()

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults("settings", {
            "dark_mode": True,
        })

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel("settings", self.config, data="""[
            {
                "type": "bool",
                "title": "Dark mode",
                "desc": "Enable dark mode",
                "section": "settings",
                "key": "dark_mode"
            }
        ]""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

The current kivy version I use is 2.1.0.

```
$ pip freeze | grep -i kivy
Kivy==2.1.0
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some digging I found a way to make this work. There seems to be a bug in Kivy after version 1.9.1 (at least that is the last version where this worked for me).
There are 2 bug reports on the Kivy list, but here is a workaround: you need to remove your widgets and recreate them. After that, changing the label text works.
Here is your modified code:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        btn1 = Button(text="Settings", size_hint=(.5, 1), on_press=self.btn1_on_press)
        self.btn2 = Button(text="0", size_hint=(.5, 1), on_press=self.btn2_on_press)
        self.add_widget(btn1)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)
        self.counter = 0

    def btn1_on_press(self, btn):
        app.open_settings()

    def btn2_on_press(self, btn):
        print("btn pressed: ", btn)
        self.counter += 1
        btn.text = str(self.counter)
        
    def redraw(self, oldValue):
        self.remove_widget(self.btn2)
        self.btn2 = Button(text=oldValue, size_hint=(.5, 1), on_press=self.btn2_on_press)
        self.add_widget(self.btn2)

class MyApp(App):
    def close_settings(self, settings=None):
        super(MyApp, self).close_settings(settings)
        self.Layout.redraw(str(self.Layout.counter))                                            # required since Kivy 2.1

    def build(self):
        self.use_kivy_settings = False
        self.Layout = MainLayout()
        return self.Layout

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults("settings", {
            "dark_mode": True,
        })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.build()
    app.run()
```

Edit: in the bug report at [bug report on github](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/8519#issuecomment-1869703489) another (easier) workaround was suggested (`import kivy.uix.settings` before opening the settings panel)